# Generating tables with images in cells using Python

Tags: python-3.x, html-table, datatable

I am pulling an assortment of data from the web using Python, and I would like to organize that data in a table format, such as HTML. My data include an image for each record, and that's the part I need help with. Can I create a table, so that I can place individual images inside the table cells?

It should / can look like this (computer component pictures in the table:
[image]

I have been looking at certain Python libraries such as Plotly and Bokeh but it doesn't look like they have this feature yet.

Answer (score 1):

Python module for handling images is called Pillow maybe it will help. Alse if you will have it in html you can use css to display it the way you want.