# Identify Table Cells Individually (Separately) using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a table, a clear table with vertical and horizontal grid lines (grid lines are sometimes black and sometimes white, it is possible to know this in advance).

I'm trying to find a way to locate each cell on the table photo individually, each cell got different properties (text, color, number, link, etc...) and I want to allow the user to perform some analysis on each cell before submitting.

When I'll show the user a given cell I will also show him the first cell from that row and the header cell for that column.

I've been searching the internet for the past 2-3 hours and found nothing, my code got me nowhere yet so there is no point in pasting it.

Some links I've tried:

1. [Generating tables with images in cells using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349309/generating-tables-with-images-in-cells-using-python)
2. [Split cells from an image of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737231/split-cells-from-an-image-of-a-table)
3. [Recognize cells from a table with Open CV and display the recognition result in QGraphicsView of PyQt5](https://ymt-lab.com/en/post/2020/pyqt5-opencv-table-recognition/)
4. [How to get individual cell in table using Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502488/how-to-get-individual-cell-in-table-using-pandas)
5. [Detect columns from a table with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452680/detect-columns-from-a-table-with-opencv)
6. [detect a table part from entire image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395631/detect-a-table-part-from-entire-image-in-python)

Most of them usually work for only extracting textual data from an image, but I do not want to extract any data, I simply want as a start to detect all of the cells in the table and display the user each of the cells (for example in a loop, show him each cell [as is, without modification] with the corresponding header and row index, meaning each iteration will show the user 3 things: {1} the cell {2} the header {3} the row index)

Example Image (Actual data is classified so I found a Google image to show the principle Im looking for):

[image: Google image]

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feM8w.png)

> I know I didn't paste any code, it's because none of the tries I did worked even a little bit, I really have no idea what to do...
>
> If you have anything you think I can do better in order to improve my question, please tell me

Answer (score 2):

(I've edited my answer to account for the fact that you can't remove the background colors)

The following code gives you the cells:

```
img = cv.imread("your_img.png",cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
## detect edges in the image. Will get the table cells and the text
## the text will be removed later
edges = cv.Canny(img,10,20)
## make the edges a bit thicker
edges = cv.dilate(edges, np.ones((3,3))) 

## invert image
_, edges = cv.threshold(edges,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
## find the contours of the cells
conts,_  = cv.findContours(edges, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
## add a convex hull around to remove the text
conts = [cv.convexHull(cont) for cont in conts]
## filter out noise
conts = [cont for cont in conts if cv.contourArea(cont) > 100]
## draw on an image
edges = cv.drawContours(edges*0, conts, -1,(1,),1)
```

[image: Here]'s the final image

Comment: I need the cells to remain as they are as I said

Comment: it's only to detect the contours, your original image can stay as it is

Comment: How will I remove the cells background then? each cell can have any background color, there is no limit to the styling it got

Comment: you can do it on the spreadsheet, select all the cells and remove the background

Comment: I do not have a spreadsheet, I have only the image

Comment: got it, see the edits

Comment: I think I might need to help rephrase my question, my meaning was, I need to give to the users, each cell individually as is, meaning each cell alone with its content, for the example only I said for example loop over all the cells and each time show my user each cell as is (without modification to the cell content)

Comment: conts above is a list where each element is a contour around the cell. You can use that to extract each cell from the original. image

Comment: Alright, I will try to use it, but how can I crop each cell individually and display it?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424852/region-of-interest-opencv-python

Comment: I tried the codes on other examples, as this one: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxzg.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxzg.jpg) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, I would expect that you can adapt the answer above to your particular problem

Comment: To be honest I tried without luck, but I'll keep on trying